# Importing a library into Android project (shared with SVN)

Tags: eclipse, svn, android-library

There's library that i want to use in my project. I have the project folder of the library so I followed these steps to add it to my project:

1. Execute "jar cf NameOfTheLibrary.jar *NameOfTheProjectFolder"
2. Create a new folder, named libs, in my Eclipse/Android project.
3. Right click libs and choose Import -> General -> File System, then click Next.
4. Browse the file system to find the library's parent directory (where I keep the generated jar file).
5. Click OK, then click the directory name (not the checkbox) in the left pane and check the relevant JAR in the right pane.
6. Right click on my project, choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path, then click the Libraries tab, then click Add JARs...
7. Navigate to my new JAR in the libs directory and add it.

Even if Eclipse doesnt notice any problem before runtime, when I start my application on my log (I use logcat) appears:

> "Could not find 'pathOf.classOf.myImported.Library' referenced from method'path.of.the.method'"

How can I import this library in a way that i can share it with the project via SVN? I thought what I've done was enough but It doesnt seem so.